# Automatically detect changes in an object from JSON from external API

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am using the fantasy premier league api to try to create an app where I update the live what events happens in each match, using the API: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/event/15/live/

This is a pure Next.js application, and I am trying to build the application without a database.

The challenge:
I am trying to display the latest event that happened in a match but each event is linked to a player, not an event. This means that if a football player scores a goal (which is an event), I need to detect that the JSON has updated with the specific players (the objects called elements is a list of different playerIDs). The events are what's in the object called "explain". I need to capture if any of the players explain object has updated. Can anybody support how I can do this with Next.js?

This is my current code to get the data:

```
export async function getGWEvents(gw: number | string) {
  const res = await fetch(`${FPL_BASE_URL}/event/${gw}/live`, {
    next: { revalidate: REVALIDATION },
  });

  const data = (await res.json()) as FPLEvents;
  console.log(data);
  
  return data;
}
```